# 'sudo' not found in Turnkey linux Ubuntu install

Tags: sudo

Just installed a turnkey linux ubuntu/apache/tomcat vm image. After [some trouble](https://serverfault.com/questions/347710/virtualbox-bridged-adapter-not-installing-on-windows-7-host/347827) getting the bridged network adapter installed on win7, I wanted to check network access to and from the vm. Verified that I could hit the vm's web server from the host, and wanted to test that I could also hit the internet from the vm, so I did this on the shell cmd line:

```
curl www.google.com
```

Which responded with this:

```
-sh: curl: not found
```

Wanting to make sure it wasn't busted networking, I tried this, and got the same response:

```
curl localhost
```

That leads me to think that wasn't curl saying it can't find the requested url, but the shell saying it can't find the curl cmd. So I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Response was:

```
-sh: sudo: not found
```

So now I'm confused. Sudo **has** to be installed, doesn't it, and apt-get? Both because they're fundamental I think, and because you couldn't install anything else without them, if you see what I mean.

Is it a security issue, that my account (which I just created via webmin) doesn't have rights to sudo? I added myself to the secondary group 'sudo' via webmin, though I wasn't sure that was legit, logged out and back in, no change, so I undid it.

I read that /etc/sudoers controls access to sudo, but as far as I can tell from both the cmd line and the webmin text editor open file dlg, it doesn't exist. Do I need to create it? Is it normal to have to do that, or a system defect?

Or is it something else that my ignorant self is or isn't doing?

Comment: On a semi-related note, you can install stuff without `apt-get` (even package managers like `apt-get` itself) using the old `make; sudo make install` procedure. Regarding `sudo`, you can use `su root -r 'command...'` or something like that, I think. It's just a bit more awkward, but possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from this forum post 
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110125/sudo-command-not-found-turnkeylinux-drupal6
it looks like, sudo isn't installed by default on turnkeylinux.
It features some help on how to install it as well.

If there are more problems with turnkey you should probably continue to ask there, since it seems to be a heavily specialized ubuntu fork.

Answer (score 7):

Whilst Turnkey Linux is based on Ubuntu (and is binary compatible - and in fact is mostly constructed of vanilla Ubuntu packages), it isn't strictly Ubuntu and has a number of customisations.

So sudo is not installed by default in TKL appliances. On a desktop it is a really good idea to have the root account disabled and use sudo instead (as Ubuntu is by default). IMO (and the TKL dev's) this rationale does not apply to servers.

With this setup sudo is generally not required. For general admin just use root (and so no need for sudo). If you want additional users you probably don't want them having admin (sudo) privileges anyway.

So to install curl (or any other command) just omit the sudo eg

```
apt-get install curl
```

If you want sudo then just install it

```
 apt-get install sudo
```

Comment: I understand the thinking, thanks. As a long-time web app dev just learning linux (especially w/o a GUI), I need admin access to get my web stacks in place, but sometimes I also want to live life as a "normal" user, together more the TKL desktop security model. If I wasn't so new to linux, I would have immediately recognized what was going on and easily worked around it. As it was, I had no idea it was even possible to create a linux system w/o sudo, so I thought I was even more clueless than I actually am, or that the install was broken. Is this documented? I have to admit, I didn't RTFTKLM.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `PATH` is wrong. `sudo` is located in `/usr/bin` folder. Try to run the complete path:

`/usr/bin/sudo -i`

Then:

`apt-get install curl`

Is there any special reason to use `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: (I was actually switching between sh and bash, just to make sure that wasn't relevant. Posted the sh results here as less verbose, but I'll just omit the prompt from here on out. And thanks to all for their assists!) From /usr/bin/, 'ls s*' doesn't show sudo, which I would take to mean it's not there. Could it be somewhere else, or is something busted or weird in this install?

Comment: No `sudo`? Yes, probably a bad installation... The `ubuntu-minimal` package depends on `sudo`. No `sudo`, no administrative tasks, no server.

Comment: Oh... turnkey linux... Had the installer asked you a `root` password?

Comment: Yes, and I know it. What next?

Comment: you can type in the shell "su" then enter your password and then install stuff just by typing apt-get install without sudo in front of it

Comment: Sorry, not following you.

Comment: if ubuntu has asked you to set a root password during the instalation you should be able to switch to the root user with the "su" command (sorry don't know how to make code markup in comments) so you'dhave to type "su" put in your password and then you are the root user and can install things. So the sudo command wouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: It sounds like the Linux you installed isn't really Ubuntu, but some derivative. After all, Ubuntu has used sudo at least since I started using it in 2006.

Comment: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110125/sudo-command-not-found-turnkeylinux-drupal6

Comment: Daniel, the link in your last post appears to be the answer -- sudo actually isn't installed in that distro. If you make it a separate answer, I'll mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the command?

```
sudo -i
```

It should ask you for your password and then log you in as root user.
If it works type

```
exit
```

to log yourself out again.
That would verify that you have `sudo` rights.

Comment: I get -sh: sudo: not found. So I don't have sudo rights then?

Comment: no..that's just weird...it means, that it doesn't find the command sudo. I didn't really get in what kind of environment you are. Is it a virtual machine?

Comment: It's a vm created from the [turnkey linux tomcat on apache appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat-apache). Seems to me like sudo is so fundamental, it'd have to be there, regardless of the specifics of the vm.

Comment: it seems unnatural for ubuntu not to have sudo, so I would say the install seems busted. Maybe you can download the sudo binary package from here gratisoft.us/sudo/download.html and let the .deb package install it

Comment: @DanielW.- very (very, very) late response, it's not busted, sudo is not included intentionally. I'm not going to repeat the rationale right now, but it's well documented if you're interested. If you want sudo, install it: 'apt-get install sudo'